# Laravel NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://laravel.dev/c

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Hi guys I'm trying out laravel now what I'm doing is whenever a user types on a textbox with their username the div above it will load an image based on the user if he/she is registered on my database but this is not happening instead it gives me an error 
here is the error found by firebug
[image]

any idea how? I tried several things found on google but didn't solve my problem 
Here is what I have

FROM the login.blade.php(the ajax only since its the only one that iniates the condition)

```
       $('#email').typing({

    start: function () {

},
    stop: function () {
        var email = $('#email').val(); 
        $.get('c',function(data){
         console.log(data);
    $('#ico-pro').html('<img src="temp/users/'+ us +'.jpg" width=75 height=75>');

  });
}
});
```

FROM the route

```
Route::get('/c','HomeController@login_c');
```

FROM the HomeController.php

```
    public function login_c()
    {
  if(Request::ajax()){
    $email = Response::json(Input::get('us'));

        $users = User::where('username','=',$email)->get();
        foreach ($users as $val):
            $firstname = $val['firstname'];
        endforeach;
    return Response::json(array('us' => $firstname));
  }
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. There's an undefined variable `$firstname` somewhere.

Comment: yeah I know that its undefined and its from the $firstname on my HomeController but IT is define there so how come its still undefined?
dont you find it odd?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your variable `$firstname` is `undefined` but maybe you are wondering yourself

> Why $firstname is undefined if it's defined inside the foreach loop?

That's because `$firstname` only is avaliable inside the `foreach's scope`.

Maybe you would like to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Block_scope)

But also think, what if `$users` does not return anything? Then `$firstname` will never be defined and that will throw an error because of an `undefined` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**Edited**);

```
$users = User::where('username','=',$email)->get();
$new_array = array();
foreach($users as $val) {
   $new_array[] = $val->first_name;
}
echo json_encode(array('us'=>$new_array));
```

Comment: it returns [] result from firebug

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
$email = Response::json(Input::get('us'));
$user = User::where('username','=',$email)->first();
return Response::json(array('us' => $user->firstname));
```